# How do I fix a "missing mcp.cfg" error?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I am trying to use mod coder pack (MCP) to create mods of my own. I have downloaded MCP 9.4 version from [www.modcoderpack.com](https://www.modcoderpack.com). The error that I have encountered is that when I try to run a file called `decompile.sh` in the mac terminal, the terminal responds with an error: `ERROR:root:!! Missing mcp.cfg`. I have checked my MCP folder and made sure that it contained the file `mcp.cfg`. The file is in my folder.

I am currently running on a Macbook Pro with MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the content of `decompile.sh` but chances are good that that script simply assumes `mcp.cfg` will be in particular location. The file is probably references as a path relative to the working directory, which is *probably* the directory you're running the script from (unless the script itself changes it).

Try `cd`ing to the directory containing `mcp.cfg` and running it from there. Failing that, you may want to edit your post to include the contents of `decompile.sh` as it will help with further diagnostics if my guess here is wrong.